# I need to capture date from multiple csv filenames and add that date in each file as a new column using Python

Tags: python

I need to capture date from multiple csv filenames and add that date in each file as a new column using Python , I have this code that works well with Excel files and I am trying to do exactly the same with CSV files, If someone could help me that would be much appreciated.

Filenames are as following...
Scan_05-22-2021.csv
Scan_05-23-2021.csv
Scan_05-24-2021.csv and so on..

Excel code that works..

```
import openpyexcel
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
import csv

from openpyexcel import load_workbook
import os

path_to_xls = os.getcwd() # or r'<path>'

for xls in os.listdir ('C:\Python'):
    if xls.endswith(".csv") or xls.endswith(".xlsx"):
        f = load_workbook(filename=xls)
        sheet = f.active
        # Change here the name of the new column
        sheet.cell(row=1, column=25).value = "DateTest"
        for i in range(sheet.max_row-1):
            #xls.split('_')[1][:-5]    #kaes value of Col1 and dumps/overwrites in column 3
            sheet.cell(row=i+2, column=25).value = xls.split('_')[1][:-5]

                f.save(xls)
                f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with pandas

use pd.read_csv to load the files as DataFrames
you can use the iterrows method to go ever rows
and simply append to the new file.

[this cheatsheet](https://pandas.pydata.org/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf) could be of use

Good luck!